Laravel Sanctum Impersonate User only works for one request
I'm using Laravel Jetstream, which uses sanctum for authentication. I'm trying to build a simple impersonate feature, and I have it working 99% of the way, but I am missing something small.
If the impersonator and the impersonated users share the same password, it works 100%, and I can refresh the page any number of times. If that isn't the case, and they have different passwords as you would normally, when you impersonate a user, it'll load the dashboard, but then any subsequent refreshes will take you to the log in screen.
I wrote up everything I did here: https://github.com/thorst/laravel-jetstream-impersonate/blob/main/README.md
This will help users in the future, once I get it working, since this is a popular topic.
In sum, here is my impersonate controller:
public function start(Request $request, $userId)
{
    // Ensure the current user has permission to impersonate
    if (!Auth::user()->canImpersonate()) {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }

    Session::put('impersonate', $userId);

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}
public function stop()
{
    // Remove impersonation data from the session
    session()->forget('impersonate');

    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
}

And my middleware:
 public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
 {
    
     // Check if impersonation is active
     if (Session::has('impersonate')) {
         $impersonatedUserId = Session::get('impersonate');

         // Find and set the impersonated user
         $impersonatedUser = \App\Models\User::find($impersonatedUserId);
         if ($impersonatedUser && $impersonatedUser.canBeImpersonated()) {
             Auth::setUser($impersonatedUser);
         }
     }

     return $next($request);
 }

Because it works 100% when I have the same password for both users, I assumed it would be this code, but adding this to the start function in the controller, or to the middleware, didnt seem to fix it.
  session()->put([
                    'password_hash_sanctum' => $impersonatedUser->getAuthPassword(),
                ]);

Any tips or guidance would help. I know there are a couple packages, but like lab404/laravel-impersonate isn't really being maintained much anymore.
Thanks,

I had the same problem. Using debugbar I found out that upon the first API call that uses the auth:sanctum middleware, a session variable 'password_hash_web', containing the hashed password, is created. This told me that NOT having the session variable is no problem for sanctum.
So I've added the following line to my impersonate and unimpersonate methods:
Session::forget('password_hash_web');

The result is that, on the next API call, sanctum will recreate the session variable instead of logging you out. I can now impersonate, unimpersonate, impersonate another user, and API requests remain functional.
